# Scroll to exit animation : Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to create an animation where the user can scroll the activity off the screen (something like Google contacts or hangouts contacts). Like scroll down from the very top of the activity will make the activity animate down till it's gone

Comment: do you wish the animation to replace the activity with otehr activity? or the content inside the activity?

Comment: Probably using fragments would be better i suppose

Comment: so you want animation between 2 fragments?

Comment: Yes, but using gestures, like scrolling down